# How to edit github repositories created by others using comand line

Tags: git, github

Hello guys i am new to git . I have seen a lot of reposistories on github.And one of my friend created a new repository in php and javascript  for making a plugin.

The question is that can i edit that php and javascript  files of that repository from the base directory by any command line using the git software.I have googled many times but i didnt get any useful answer .Any help would be appreciated .ThankS IN advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can definitely do what you are asking.

The command-line has the `git` command which can be used to clone a repository, commit changes to it, and push those changes back.

Due to the nature of your question, I'll assume you have some basic Git knowledge.  If not, check out this tutorial: http://try.github.io/

OK, so your friend has a GitHub repository and you would like to make changes to the files in this repository.  There are two ways to do this.  I'll explain the less common, but easier solution first, and the more common but more complex way second.

1) Become a Collaborator of the Repo

This option is very simple.  All you do is ask your friend to add you as a Collaborator on their repo.  They do this by going to their repo on github, clicking the settings for their repo, going to the Collaborators section, and adding your name to the list of collaborators.

Then you can just clone, commit your changes, and push straight to your friend's repo.

2) Fork the Repo and Submit a Pull Request

This option is a bit more complex, but gives your friend the right to approve or revoke your changes to the repo.  To do this you go to the GitHub page for your friend's repository and click the Fork button (currently located on the top-right of the page).  This will make a clone of your friend's repository under your GitHub account.

Now you can clone your own copy of the repository, commit your changes, and push to your repo.  At this point your changes are not yet on your friend's repo - they are in your copy of the repo!  To get your changes into your friend's repo you need to open a pull request for your friend to approve.  Use the GitHub interface to open the pull request and your friend will be notified.

Hopefully that answers your questions.

Comment: This answer clarifies some of the things that have been mystifying me as a git/github beginner. I have a relevant question you may be able to help with. I have 'copied' a repository from github,: I think I used 'git clone', not 'fork on github', but I'm sort of overwhelmed by all the newness at the moment and I'm not sure. How can I tell whether I'm using (looking at?) the original repository or a forked one? Either in Github desktop (Mac) or on the command line?

Comment: @Max I don't used GUI clients for git so I wouldn't know how to use the Desktop Mac client.  But, on the command line, what you want to check is what your origin repository is set to with `git remote show origin`.  This will list what repository you will be fetching from (`git pull`) and pushing to (`git push`) when using the default origin remote and usually tells you where you cloned your repo from.

Comment: Many thanks: I was expecting to find something in `git show`, and getting frustrated. `git remote show` makes sense now! Part of the problem is I'm not sure if a particular "feature" is intrinsic to git, or part of the Gitub workflow. It's all gradually becoming clearer now.